# PHP rand() exclude certain numbers

Tags: php

I have this:

```
<?php  $n = rand(1,1600); echo $n ?>
```

I want to exclude from random numbers let's say 234, 1578 ,763 , 1274 and other numbers. How would I do that?

Comment: Don't use rand! Use [mt_rand](http://php.net/mt_rand), or better [random_int](http://php.net/random_int) if you come from PHP7.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<?php

while( in_array( ($n = mt_rand(1,1600)), array(234, 1578 ,763 , 1274) ) );
```

Comment: Don't use rand, use mt_rand, or better random_int if you come from PHP7.

Comment: While this one works, using assignment in loop always scares me :|

Comment: @emix Now it doesn't matter, because `rand()` is a synonym of `mt_rand()`

Comment: You get an extra opcode when using an alias. Still, `random_int` is much better.

Answer (score 12):

Try like this

```
do {   
    $n = rand(1,1600);

} while(in_array($n, array(234, 1578 ,763 , 1274 ));
echo $n;
```

Comment: it will check whether the generated number is in array or not ,if they are present then again it will goto the do-while loop

Comment: Need to correct he answer little bit like, there is ")" missing at the end. Just for correction so that othr can easily copy and test your answer for implementation

Answer (score 8):

Check if the number is one that you don't want, if it is get a new random number.

```
function getRandomNumber() {
    do {
        $n = mt_rand(1,1600);
    } while(in_array($n, array(234,1578, 763, 1274)));

    return $n;
}
```

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta - why make it recursive, if a while loop works perfectly?

Comment: Updated my while condition, so that adding new numbers is easier.

Comment: missing a closing ) on while

Answer (score 2):

Always use cryptographically strong algorithms for generating random numbers:

```
/**
 * @param int   $from     From number
 * @param int   $to       To number
 * @param array $excluded Additionally exclude numbers
 * @return int
 */
function randomNumber($from, $to, array $excluded = [])
{
    $func = function_exists('random_int') ? 'random_int' : 'mt_rand';

    do {
        $number = $func($from, $to);
    } while (in_array($number, $excluded, true));

    return $number;
}

var_dump(randomNumber(1, 100));
var_dump(randomNumber(1, 10, [5, 6, 7, 8]));
var_dump(randomNumber(1, 100, range(10, 90)));
```

I'd also recommend using the [paragonie/random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) library for compatibility in case of using multiple PHP versions.

Answer (score 1):

Or avoid making loops with random (possibly infinite) running time:

```
/**
 * Returns a random integer between $min and $max (inclusive) and
 * excludes integers in $exarr, returns false if no such number
 * exists.
 * 
 * $exarr is assumed to be sorted in increasing order and each
 * element should be unique.
 */
function random_exclude($min, $max, $exarr = array()) {

    if ($max - count($exarr) < $min) {
        return false;
    }

    // $pos is the position that the random number will take
    // of all allowed positions
    $pos = rand(0, $max - $min - count($exarr));

    // $num being the random number
    $num = $min;

    // while $pos > 0, step to the next position
    // and decrease if the next position is available
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($exarr); $i += 1) {

        // if $num is on an excluded position, skip it
        if ($num == $exarr[$i]) {
            $num += 1;
            continue;
        }

        $dif = $exarr[$i] - $num;

        // if the position is after the next excluded number,
        // go to the next excluded number
        if ($pos >= $dif) {
            $num += $dif;

            // -1 because we're now at an excluded position
            $pos -= $dif - 1;
        } else {
            // otherwise, return the free position
            return $num + $pos;
        }
    }

    // return the number plus the open positions we still had to go
    return $num + $pos;
}
```

This function chooses a random position and walks the exclusion array to find the free position. It's running time depends on the amount of numbers to exclude. If you want to exclude certain ranges, you may want to adapt the algorithm to take this into account.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for this could be as follows:

```
function random_number($min, $max, $exclude)
{
      $number = rand($min, $max);

  if(in_array($number, $exclude))
  {
      random_number($min, $max, $exclude);
  } else {
      return $number;
  }
}

$number = random_number(1,10, [2,5,6]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the volume of "blacklisted" integers approaches the volume of the full range of integers, it becomes increasingly compelling to take the advice of @regenschein.

A non-iterative approach might look like this:

```
$range = range(1, 1600);
$blacklist = [234, 1578, 763, 1274]; // 4 blacklisted versus 1600 full range is NOT compelling
$valids = array_diff($range, $blacklist);
echo array_values($valids)[rand(0, count($valids) - 1)];
// or
echo $valids[array_rand($valids)];
// the two approaches use different randomizers
```

Or if you'd be just as happy shuffling, you could do:

```
$blacklist = [234, 1578, 763, 1274];
$range = range(1, 1600);
$valids = array_diff($range, $blacklist);
shuffle($valids);
echo $valids[0];
```

*Note `array_diff()` is particularly great if you want to pass multiple blacklist arrays -- just comma-separate them.

For example:

```
var_export($valids = array_diff(range(1, 100), range(5, 50), range(61, 99), [55]));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 4,
  50 => 51,
  51 => 52,
  52 => 53,
  53 => 54,
  55 => 56,
  56 => 57,
  57 => 58,
  58 => 59,
  59 => 60,
  99 => 100,
)
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer than the accepted one (at least when the list of exceptions is big)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old,but I think what the op tries to do is shuffle the integers. If so the following method is better

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
shuffle($array);
```

This code will randomize the order of the array's exact elements without repetition and return the result inside the array itself.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array with valid numbers.

Then, your random number generation should return the index into that array.

Comment: This is by far the cleanest solution - all the others are either recursive or use loops that can, in theory, be endless and also promote bad programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many numbers to exclude, it is easier and faster to just retry if you find an unwanted number:

```php
$n = 0;
while (in_array($n, array(0, 234, 1578 ,763 , 1274))) {
  $n = rand(1,1600); 
}

echo $n;
```